# I am Unable to load server class 'com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher' and i am using gwt and oracle server with ojdbc5.jar

Tags: gwt, jdbc

Unable to load server class

> com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher'
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode$ArgHandlerServer.setString(DevMode.java:118)
>       at com.google.gwt.util.tools.ArgHandlerString.handle(ArgHandlerString.java:26)
>       at com.google.gwt.util.tools.ToolBase.processArgs(ToolBase.java:238)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.ArgProcessorBase.processArgs(ArgProcessorBase.java:29)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:310)
>   Google Web Toolkit 2.4.0
>   DevMode [-noserver] [-port port-number | "auto"] [-whitelist whitelist-string] [-blacklist blacklist-string] [-logdir directory] [-logLevel level] [-gen dir] [-bindAddress host-name-or-address] [-codeServerPort port-number | "auto"] [-server servletContainerLauncher[:args]] [-startupUrl url] [-war dir] [-deploy dir] [-extra dir] [-workDir dir] module[s]
>
> where 
>     -noserver        Prevents the embedded web server from running
>     -port            Specifies the TCP port for the embedded web server (defaults to 8888)
>     -whitelist       Allows the user to browse URLs that match the specified regexes (comma or space separated)
>     -blacklist       Prevents the user browsing URLs that match the specified regexes (comma or space separated)
>     -logdir          Logs to a file in the given directory, as well as graphically
>     -logLevel        The level of logging detail: ERROR, WARN, INFO, TRACE, DEBUG, SPAM, or ALL
>     -gen             Debugging: causes normally-transient generated types to be saved in the specified directory
>     -bindAddress     Specifies the bind address for the code server and web server (defaults to 127.0.0.1)
>     -codeServerPort  Specifies the TCP port for the code server (defaults to 9997)
>     -server          Specify a different embedded web server to run (must implement ServletContainerLauncher)
>     -startupUrl      Automatically launches the specified URL
>     -war             The directory into which deployable output files will be written (defaults to 'war')
>     -deploy          The directory into which deployable but not servable output files will be written (defaults to 'WEB-INF/deploy' under the -war directory/jar, and may be the same as the -extra directory/jar)
>     -extra           The directory into which extra files, not intended for deployment, will be written
>     -workDir         The compiler's working directory for internal use (must be writeable; defaults to a system temp dir)
>   and 
>     module[s]        Specifies the name(s) of the module(s) to host